# Products not appearing in Magento search results, despite being search enabled

Tags: magento

*(Yes I know this is a duplicate, but none of the other solutions work for me.)*

I’ve got a product that won’t appear in search results, despite being search enabled.

Here is an image to prove it. 
[image: showing no results]

And I’m using the latest version of Magento CE version 1.7.0

I've reindexed several times and have disabled the cache.

Please help! I can’t setup my shop without this.

Comment: Have you made sure that the 'name' attribute is set to be searchable?

Comment: Really? You have to make *attributes* searchable? ........ How do I do that? Why isn't it like that by default?

Comment: Product name will be searchable by default yes, unless it has been changed.  Others may not though.  You can check this in catalog > attributes > manage attributes.  Out of interest, do you get the correct result if you search for 'Cadbury' instead?

Comment: No I don't get any results for that either? And yes, the `name` attribute is searchable.

Comment: Yes I have several times. And I disabled the cache.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is this an upgrade from a previous version?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
1. Check product Quantity and Stock and that product is assigned to a category
2. Clear Cache
3. Run Re-Indexing.
```

Comment: Create a category and assign the product and check through top navigation.

Comment: I assigned it to a category that wasn't the root level, and it now works! It turns out that products just being in the root category, isn't enough to have them show up. Thanks.

Comment: Good answer! By default, magento excludes from search products that have inventory = 0 or out of stock - you can bypass this rule, setting "Display out of stock products" = "Yes" in System -> Configuration -> Inventory -> Stock options. Don't forget to [Save config]

Comment: Does anybody know why we have to check that `product is assigned to a category`? I too have had this problem and it turns out that the specific product wasn't assigned to any categories. Any idea why it won't work like that?

Comment: The product does not need to be assigned to a category, there is a post I recommend for this issue: http://www.aschroder.com/2010/07/why-are-my-magento-products-not-showing-up/

Comment: Make sure your products are associated with a website if you have a more complex Magento setup with multiple stores etc. You can do this as a bulk action in the products section.

Answer (score 4):

Try to change the Search Type from like to fulltext

Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Check the MySql variable **ft min word len**. I had a similar issue, if I searched for the word "Pad" it returned 0 results because the **ft min word len** variable was set to 4 charachters and the word 'pad' has only 3.

Warning: Changing the value of the **ft min word len** variable to 3 may affect your server performance.

Comment: Thanks! This solve the issue for me! We have technical product names and a search is often comprised of four 2 or 3 char. words.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem and it turned out, that the Website-Checkbox (on the Products' tab "Website" in the Magento Backend) was not set during import.

Tried the following (still working on development-site)

1. Re-Index all Data
2. Delete the Cache
3. Delete all Session Files (`rm -rf session/*` in var/)

Checked Product Settings for:

- Stock
- Visibility
- Status
- Selected Categories
- Website

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing around with these for years. Here is what I currently have setup.

catalog catalog/search (in admin) 
2
25
128
combine like/full text
2000

attributes: that are searchable
name, short_description, sku, color, manufacturer_part_number, manufacturer, upc

I did have description searchable but found that it returns way too many results..I just really want the search text found in my products name to be found.

Answer (score 0):

Our client had created a new Root Category and moved all their products under here. They had neglected to update the Main Website Store configuration in:-

```
"System/Manage Stores/Main Website Store/Root Category"
```

We set this to the "New Root Category" and the search sprang back into life :)